# One to Many equivalent in Cassandra and data model optimization

Tags: nosql, cassandra

I am modeling my database in Cassandra, coming from RDBMS. I want to know how can I create a one-to-many relationship which is embedded in the same Column Name and model my table to fit the following query needs.

For example:

```
Boxes:{
  23442:{
    belongs_to_user: user1,
    box_title: 'the box title',
    items:{
      1: {
         name: 'itemname1',
         size: 44
      },
      2: {
        name: 'itemname2',
        size: 24
      }
    }
  },

 { ... }
}
```

I read that its preferable to use composite columns instead of super columns, so I need an example of the best way to implement this. My queries are like:

- Get items for box by Id
- get top 20 boxes with their items (for displaying a range of boxes with their items on the page)
- update items size by item id (increment size by a number)
- get all boxes by userid (all boxes that belongs to a specific user)

I am expecting lots of writes to change the size of each item in the box. I want to know the best way to implement it without the need to use super columns. Furthermore, I don't mind getting a solution that takes Cassandra 1.2 new features into account, because I will use that in production.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This particular model is somewhat challenging, for a number of reasons.

For example, with the box ID as a row key, querying for a range of boxes will require a range query in Cassandra (as opposed to a column slice), which means the use of an ordered partitioner.  An ordered partitioner is almost always a *Bad Idea*.

Another challenge comes from the need to increment the item size, as this calls for the use of a counter column family.  Counter column families store counter values *only*.

Setting aside the need for a range of box IDs for a moment, you could model this using multiple tables in CQL3 as follows:

```
CREATE TABLE boxes (                                                                       
   id int PRIMARY KEY,                                                                 
   belongs_to_user text,                                                               
   box_title text,                                                                     
);
CREATE INDEX useridx on boxes (belongs_to_user);

CREATE TABLE box_items (                                                                   
   id int,                                                                             
   item int,                                                                           
   size counter,                                                                       
   PRIMARY KEY(id, item)                                                               
);

CREATE TABLE box_item_names (
    id int PRIMARY KEY,
    item int,
    name text
);

BEGIN BATCH
  INSERT INTO boxes (id, belongs_to_user, box_title) VALUES (23442, 'user1', 'the box title');
  INSERT INTO box_items (id, item, name) VALUES (23442, 1, 'itemname1');
  INSERT INTO box_items (id, item, name) VALUES (23442, 1, 'itemname2');
  UPDATE box_items SET size = size + 44 WHERE id = 23442 AND item = 1;                       
  UPDATE box_items SET size = size + 24 WHERE id = 23442 AND item = 2;
APPLY BATCH

-- Get items for box by ID                                                               
SELECT size FROM box_items WHERE id = 23442 AND item = 1;

-- Boxes by user ID
SELECT * FROM boxes WHERE belongs_to_user = 'user1';
```

It's important to note that the BATCH mutation above is both atomic, and isolated.

Technically speaking, you could also denormalize all of this into a single table.  For example:

```
CREATE TABLE boxes (
   id int,
   belongs_to_user text,
   box_title text,
   item int,
   name text,
   size counter,
   PRIMARY KEY(id, item, belongs_to_user, box_title, name)
);

UPDATE boxes set size = item_size + 44 WHERE id = 23442 AND belongs_to_user = 'user1'
    AND box_title = 'the box title' AND name = 'itemname1' AND item = 1;

SELECT item, name, size FROM boxes WHERE id = 23442;
```

*However, this provides no guarantees of correctness*.  For example, this model makes it possible for items of the same box to have different users, or titles.  And, since this makes `boxes` a counter column family, it limits how you can evolve the schema in the future.

Comment: you put `size counter` as a column key for `box_items` column family. But in INSERT query, you are adding name (`box_items (id, item, name)`). Can you please explain where is that size inserted?

Answer (score 0):

I think in PlayOrm's objects first, then show the column model below....

```
Box {
   @NoSqlId
   String id;
   @NoSqlEmbedded
   List<Item> items;
}

User {
   @NoSqlId
   TimeUUID uuid;
   @OneToMany
   List<Box> boxes;
}
```

The User then is a row like so

```
rowkey = uuid=<someuuid> boxes.fkToBox35 = null, boxes.fktoBox37=null, boxes.fkToBox38=null
```

Note, the form of the above is columname=value where some of the columnnames are composite and some are not.

The box is more interesting and say Item has fields name and idnumber, then box row would be

```
rowkey = id=myid, items.item23.name=playdo, items.item23.idnumber=5634, itesm.item56.name=pencil, items.item56.idnumber=7894
```

I am not sure what you meant though on get the top 20 boxes?  top boxes meaning by the number of items in them?

Dean

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Top 20 boxes, means that the boxes are inserted  by the user into the database, I want to get the top 20 that were inserted last in terms of data time. Like getting the top 10 comments from a long list of comments, so I can paged it in my application and make Page 1, Page 2, Page 3 and show in each all the  boxes sorted according to the data/time that they inserted

Answer (score 0):

You can use **Query-Driven Methodology**, for data modeling.You have the three broad access paths:
 1) partition per query
 2) partition+ per query (one or more partitions)
 3) table or table+ per query

The most efficient option is the “**partition per query**”. [This](http://www.cs.wayne.edu/andrey/papers/TR-BIGDATA-05-2015-CKL.pdf) article can help you in this case, step-by-step. it's sample is exactly a **one-to-many relation**.

And according to [this](http://www.datastax.com/dev/blog/basic-rules-of-cassandra-data-modeling), you will have several tables with some similar columns. You can manage this, by **Materialized View** or batch-log(as alternative approach).